# Send variable from client to database over the Server

Tags: mysql, node.js, socket.io

i have three different Files. 
app.js / DataBase.js and the client.html. 
In the app.js file i start my server with node.js - express.js and open a websocket. (see below) In Database.js i create a connection with my mysql Database. 
I was able to send the data from the database to my client page like this:

```
db = require('./mysql');
io.on('connection', function (WebSocket) {
WebSocket.on('new_data', function (name) {
WebSocket.emit('data_from_the_database', db.DataexportFromDataBase);
}); 
});
```

But now: The user should send the app.js File the varaible "name" which should used in the query from the dataexportFromDataBase. 
How i can send the variable to the dataBase file? with socket.io?

i tried:
Include the dataBaseConnection in the app.js. There was no problem and i can handle that, but i want three different files. (Server / Database with the querys / Client). I guess my problem ist here:

```
WebSocket.emit('data_from_the_database', 'db.DataExportFromDataBase');
```

Need help :)